# What happens when you make a spelling error in a dependent claim?

Tags: law, missing

In reference to the patent: [US8325025](https://www.google.com/patents/US8325025).  Claim 19: "qeo-fence" supposed to be "geo-fence."

Answer (score 1):

Typographical errors in issued patents can be fixed by filing a certificate of correction with the USPTO. It's not possible to correct it by making amendments like before or during examination because this patent is already issued.

Such an obvious typographical error would likely have little effect on validity, and at the very worst, would only create an issue for this dependent claim alone (although this is unlikely).